# Ember 2, Performances using plugin like ember-truth-helpers instead of just the Ember default way

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-data, computed-properties

If I use this plugin: `https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers`

with many, let's say,

`{{#if (eq model.beautiful true) }}`

or

`{{#if (or (eq model.beautiful true) (eq model.crazy true) ) }}`

what is Ember creating in background? The same javascript works of computedProperties like these:

`isBeautiful: Ember.computed.equal('model.beautiful', true);` and so on?

If I have 30 computedProperty (Ember macros and custom ones) it's better to use this plugin or the default Ember way?

I'm wondering because in some templates I can have something like this many many times!:

`{{#if (or (eq model.beautiful true) (eq model.crazy true) ) }}`

instead of just this one:

`{{#if isBeautifulOrCrazy }}`

What is the best solution in terms of performances?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think users will notice any difference. My choice is less code and better maintanability when possible. In your case, if you have more than 3 of the same lines `{{#if (or (eq model.beautiful true) (eq model.crazy true) ) }}`, I'd suggest computed property. It will make templates much simplier and controller insignificantly bigger. If you have the same exact line across few templates, you can create computed property on model, so it would be `{{#if model.isBeautifulOrCrazy }}`. Or a template helper.

> what is Ember creating in background?

Any helper is just a function that returns some value. `eq` helper will look like this:

```
function eq([l, r]) {
  return l === r;
}
```

When ember renders template, it evaluates this function and then uses it's value. And rerender happens if one of arguments was changed. I think that under the hood it is something similar to CP.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference will be negligible.  If you have a lot of conditional logic, it will be cleaner to use computed properties.  For simple conditions, with one or two comparisons, using the helpers is fine.

`ember-truth-helpers` provides some simple helpers so you don't have to write them yourself.  IF you prefer, you can simply create your own helpers, especially if you don't like how `ember-truth-helpers` compares values.  For most people, `ember-truth-helpers` does exactly what they want.

> what is Ember creating in background?

Let's take a look at one example: `eq`

Here is what `ember-truth-helpers` is doing:

```
export function isEqual([a, b]) {
  return emberIsEqual(a, b);
}
```

And here is the `emberIsEqual()` method it's calling from `Ember`.

```
export default function isEqual(a, b) {
  if (a && typeof a.isEqual === 'function') {
    return a.isEqual(b);
  }

  if (a instanceof Date && b instanceof Date) {
    return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
  }

  return a === b;
}
```